# automatic \allowbreak around mathbin and mathrel characters

Tags: math-mode, line-breaking

I would like linebreaks to be permitted within math formulas on both sides of any characters of the `mathbin` and `mathrel` character classes. It seems like linebreaking is by default only permitted after these characters:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

text text text text text text text text text text text text \(x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x\)

i text text text text text text text text text text text text \(x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x\)

text text text text text text text text text text text text \(x + x + x + x + x \allowbreak+ x + x + x + x\)

text text text text text text text text text text text text \(x = x = x = x = x = x = x = x = x\)

text text text text text text text text text text text text \(x = x = x = x = x \allowbreak= x = x = x = x\)

\end{document}
```

Oddly, I have also seen situations where an `\allowbreak` afterwards had an effect (that was after a `\cong` symbol), but I cannot reconstruct an example right now.

**How can I automatically allow linebreaks around `mathbin` and `mathrel` symbols?** Of course I could always manually insert `\allowbreak` or include it in my own macros defining such operators as well as `\let`-redefine the existing such symbols occurring in my document, but that seems like the wrong approach.

I know what I am doing stylistically; what I typeset is not ordinary math with run-of-the-mill equations, plus I really like having an indication of formula continuation at the *beginning* of the next line. In any case, I think for example that in something like `a = b = c⋅d`  a line break before the second equals sign looks perfectly fine. Basically, I would in some sense like to get rid of LaTeX's preference.

I'm looking for a way to (1) give the left-hand side of such a symbol the same status as its right-hand side or (2) to basically insert automatic `\allowbreak`s around such symbols. (Note that these two options are not the same.) Note that this ideally shouldn't screw up more complex math symbols built with existing or self-defined `mathbin`/`mathrel` symbols.

Comment: A line break in an in-line equation should happen *after* an operation or relation symbol, so the reader will have a clue that the equation isn't over. Indeed, TeX (reluctantly) breaks after these symbols, but *not* before unless manually instructed to do so.

Comment: @egreg Thanks for the details, *but* my preference is different. (Such a symbol at the *beginning* of the next line *also* tells readers that the formula is continued, assuming the reader parses the start of the next line and doesn't abruptly stop reading. This is in fact the default case of sentence processing: Even when reading ordinary sentences, the fact that many sentences stretch over multiple lines means that line-final expressions can be misparsed unless the reader continues the reading process.) -- If it's *impossible* to do in LaTeX, I'd rather hear that directly.

Comment: Btw, fwiw, I've also seen a style where (say) a plus sign is repeated, that is it is typeset both at the end of the first line and the beginning of the second line.

Comment: The principle is exactly the same as what's used when splitting a word: the hyphen is *not* at the start of the new line. If one reads "a=b+c" at the end of a line will take this as a complete equation; with "a=b+c+", it would be clear that the equation is not complete. Repeating the symbol is used in Russian typography; it's quite ambiguous and useless, IMO.

Comment: @egreg Yes, but it's an opinion. For my view: (1) formulas are visually distinct, (2) formulas are very often set off typographically, and (3) readers need to spend more time on formulas anyways, so there isn't really any risk of misparsing. There is an opposite convention for URLs, where many recommend to break a URL *before* a period, for example. It doesn't matter; this is a classic case where someone defends a LaTeX default, which is of limited help; no offense intended. (Some people will do this no matter what.) I'd like to know how to do it or have an answer proving it impossible.

Comment: @egreg (1) Btw the Russian system allows (*in principle* - dunno whether this is how it's used) for a distinction between a true and a line-breaking hyphen. Some people don't care about preserving such information, of course; an example is the German lack of paragraph indentation, where you very occasionally can't tell whether a new paragraph begins or not. (2) I don't understand the general guard against repetition of information. There are a million things in a book that are strictly speaking redundant, such as the TOC, page numbers, and an index, not to mention much of expository content.

Comment: the russian convention was discussed briefly in [a tugboat article by mikhail grinchuk](http://tug.org/TUGboat/tb17-4/tb53grin.pdf), with suggested macros `\brokenrel` and `\brokenbin` to be used in situations where such breaks were needed.  this was relevant to plain tex, but may contain some ideas that could be useful in the present situation.

Comment: Off topic, but: “the German lack of paragraph indentation” Where did you get that impression from? I just took a look in a number (>10) of books from my shelf (all from different publishers) and all of them except one child's book had paragraph indentation.

Comment: @cgnieder Thanks for your message; if I am wrong, I stand corrected :-) Perhaps I remembered incorrectly? My somewhat older edition of the grammar Duden (vol. 4) uses no indentation (but interestingly makes a distinction between slightly increasing the inter-paragraph spacing or not doing this). It seems like either things have changed or there is variation across genres (or I remembered incorrectly in the first place). You might be right.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `flexisym` package allows arbitrary commands to be inserted into math character definitions. It is usually used in conjunction with `breqn` for which it was written but here I use it directly. the definition of binary and relation functions are a bit opaque but just copied directly from the existing definition with the addition of `\allowbreak` as in your example, but applied to all characters of those classes (as long as they are defined via the standard LaTeX declarations).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{flexisym}

\begingroup
\catcode`\_11
\catcode`\:11
\gdef\math_bsym_Bin:Nn#1#2{%
 \allowbreak\math_char:NNn 2#1{#2}\allowbreak}
\gdef\math_bsym_Rel:Nn#1#2{%
 \allowbreak\math_char:NNn 3#1{#2}\allowbreak}
\endgroup

\begin{document}


text text text text text text text text text text text text \(x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x\)

i text text text text text text text text text text text text \(x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x\)

text text text text text text text text text text text text \(x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x\)

text text text text text text text text text text text text \(x = x = x = x = x = x = x = x = x\)

text text text text text text text text text text text text \(x = x = x = x = x = x = x = x = x\)

\end{document}
```

Comment: As for "standard LaTeX declarations", is it okay if I define something with `\newcommand{\macroname}{\mathbin{...}}`?

Comment: The wording was just copied from the flexisym documentation. I think if you use primitives like that it depends exactly what the `...` is. The official LaTeX syntax to declare a binary operator is of course `\DeclareMathSymbol{+}{\mathbin}{operators}{"2B}`

Comment: Let me further add that `flexisym` necessitates that a lot of superscripts and subscripts like `...^+` and `...^\somecommand{somearg}` will now have to be enclosed in braces (`...^{+}` and `...^{\somecommand{somearg}}`, respectively).

Comment: Of course that requirement is also explicit in the latex manual (not that anyone follows it) see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/82329/how-bad-for-tex-is-omitting-braces-even-if-the-result-is-the-same/82337#82337

Comment: Importing `flexsym` (without anything else) broke all my maths environments on xelatex. Instead I recommend this answer which lets you redefine your maths operators and you can add `\allowbreak` that way: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/299805/169711